# Proving that $\frac{R[x]}{I[x]} \cong \frac{R}{I} [x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I define the map $$\phi : R[x] \to \frac{R}{I}[x], \quad
 \phi\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i x^i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^n \left(a_i+I\right)x^i $$
I know how to prove everything needed here except for showing that $\phi(a\cdot b)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(b)$.
I have seen other questions on this site regarding this but none of them addressed the part I'm stuck in. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Well for this you can either prove it by hand, or using the universal property of the polynomial ring

Comment: @Max I've tried proving it by hand and I'm unable to do it. Universal property of rings?

Comment: If you want to do it by hand you can use induction.  Given $a \in R[x]$ use induction on the degree of $b$.

Comment: @sykh oh yes thanks.

Comment: The universal property of $R[X]$ is that for any $R$-algebra $B$ and element $a\in B$, there is a unique *morphism* $f: R[X] \to B$ such that $f(X) = a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

By linearity, you only have to prove $\;\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\,\phi(b)$ for a pair of *monomials*.

Comment: Lol. I'm so stupid to not see that. Thanks